# Load data from Database using Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have this code to display the data retrieved from DB in `accounts_view.php`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showPrice(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("sender_price").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("sender_price").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","?action=account&q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

I have problem in the below line :

`xmlhttp.open("GET","?action=account&q="+str,true);`

Just to explain to you I have `index.php` and have many cases there, I have

```
case "account" :

$q=$_GET["q"];

//code is here to get data from db and return with result..

include($_STR_TEMPLATEPATH."/account_view.php");

break;
```

So, When I am redirecting to `?action=account&q=str` in the `account_view.php`

it displays the page again, so I will have 2 pages over each other.

I hope the problem is clear to you :)

Thanks and Regards,

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would recommend using [jquery](http://jquery.com/) to retrieve data from a database if you are wanting to use ajax.  All the browser incompatibilities are already accounted for and you won't have to bother coding for all the issues you will encounter trying to accomplish this by hand.  basically why re-invent the wheel that is already perfectly created.

Here is an example of my code using jquery and how easy it is to use.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>some title</title>
<link href="customize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link href="css/black-tie/jquery-ui-1.8rc3.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.8rc3.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function ShowActive(inputString){
     //gives visual that something is happening
     $('#Sresults').addClass('loading');
     //send your data to a php script here i am only sending one variable
     //if using more than one then use json format
     $.post("allactive.php", {queryString: ""+inputString+""}, function(data){
       if(data.length >0) {
         //populate div with results
         $('#Sresults').html(data);
         $('#Sresults').removeClass('loading');
       }
     });
   }
</script>
</head>
<body>
  put your form here ....
  <div id="Sresults" name="Sresults"></div>
</body>
```